# Why does Microsoft typedef twice in their winnt.h file, when declaring what constitutes as "double"?

Tags: c++, windows

```
#if defined(_MAC) && defined(_MAC_INT_64)
typedef __int64 LONGLONG;
typedef unsigned __int64 ULONGLONG;

#define MAXLONGLONG                      (0x7fffffffffffffff)


#else
typedef double LONGLONG;
typedef double ULONGLONG;
#endif //_MAC and int64

#endif
```

Inside the C++ header file winnt.h (which I believe is the file that decides what constitutes as a `short`, `int`, `double`, etc) I noticed Microsoft typedefs a few variables twice within the same preprocessor conditional scope.

What would be the point of this? Wouldn't a `double` always be what it's last typedef assignment was? Is there some kind of architecture assignment checking that occurs by first attempting to typedef the `double` as LONGLONG?

Comment: .h files are usually C headers I believe, whereas .hpp files are C++ headers. But you're right, Double did actually exist in C so I'm not sure.

Comment: You're misreading the syntax. 'double' is the target type. LONGLONG and ULONGLONG are the new type names being introduced by the typedefs respectively. There is no duplication here.

Comment: The point is to define `LONGLONG` and `ULONGLONG` as 8-byte types. If the compiler supports 64-bit integers, then using `__int64` is quick and easy. Otherwise, `double` is a 8-byte primitive type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typedef` defines the *right-hand side*, not the left-hand side. In this case, the types being defined are `LONGLONG` and `ULONGLONG`, not `double`.

Comment: Right, but if they're both just double anyways, then why? +1 still because it's correct

Comment: Because on other platforms, `LONGLONG` is actually defined as `__int64` and `ULONGLONG` is defined as `unsigned __int64`. So source code can just use `LONGLONG` and `ULONGLONG` and get the expected behaviour regardless of the platform in use.

Comment: Wow, microsoft does this? Boy does this break numbers greater than 2^53 badly...!